# facebook api return only top 4 LIKES

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing problem when getting LIKES of Photos.
In result i m getting **top 4** likes only.
How can i get all likes.
Photo has more than 10 likes but it is showing only top 4 likes.

Below is example
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150146071831729

this photo have more then 200 likes but if you see in graph explorer tool as below it return only 4 likes

https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071831729/likes

really appreciate your help.

Thanks
Samir

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your code.

Comment: I am simply accessing from graph as below https://graph.facebook.com/<photoid>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is fixed Now from facebook....
and it is working fine now...

Thanks all for support

Samir

Answer (score 0):

Edit by me: **This is actually a knew bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/248604125193508**

---

In fact, it's explicated in the data returned:

```
"likes": {
      "data": [
         {
            "id": "100002201984352",
            "name": "Ranjeet Pardeshi"
         },
         {
            "id": "100003051413850",
            "name": "Oshadhi Amashakya Senawirathna"
         },
         {
            "id": "100002675505310",
            "name": "Myda Jaz"
         },
         {
            "id": "100002420622515",
            "name": "Sirat Keling"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071831729/likes?limit=25&offset=25"
      }
   }
```

You have "4" likes in the "data". And the "next" likes are accessible by the url. https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071831729/likes?limit=25&offset=25

If you want just the likes's data, you can use directly https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071831729/likes?limit=5000 for example.

You can read also this post [facebook php, how do you use results paging?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8211177/facebook-php-how-do-you-use-results-paging/8211766#8211766) about how to get ALL the next results in "paging".

Comment: Thanks for your reply but when i using this link graph.facebook.com/10150146071831729/likes?limit=5000 that u mention still i m getting only 4 records

Comment: Forgive my explanation... My link doesn't work more :( Indeed it's a bit awkward..

Comment: i tried in my real photo still same problem i m specifying limit=25 but it still returns only 4 and on next page showing blank

Comment: Yeah.. Same result with FQL. https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20user_id%20FROM%20like%20WHERE%20object_id%3D%2210150146071831729%22 It seems to be a problem with an access token but I don't see why we get these 4 results.

Comment: is there any other way where i can get all LIKES. Actually i have fan page have Photos in Album of this Fan Page now i need to get LIkes of all that Photos

Comment: Honestly I don't know. You can try to fill a bug ticket on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ or maybe wait another answer :)

Comment: And in fact, there is already two reports here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/248604125193508?browse=search_4ecb7e5f3a6fe0a81977917 and here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194752153940077?browse=search_4ecb7e5f3a6fe0a81977917. So just wait :)